# How to make constriants in gekko by for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, constraints, linear-programming, gekko

By tips in [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64542594/11217085) for using dictionaries as source input to gekko, I did as below;

```
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
my_vars = ['x1','x2','x3']

# stored as dictionaries

Cost = {'x1':100,'x2':125,'x3':80}
Min = {'x1':0,'x2':0,'x3':0}
Max = {'x1':70,'x2':40,'x3':15}

LP = GEKKO(remote=False)
va = LP.Array(LP.Var, (len(my_vars)))  # array
vd = {}                                # dictionary
for i,xi in enumerate(my_vars):
    vd[xi] = va[i]
    vd[xi].lower = Min[xi]
    vd[xi].upper = Max[xi]

# Cost function
LP.Minimize(LP.sum([Cost[xi]*vd[xi] for xi in my_vars])) 

# This also works as a dictionary
LP.Equation(LP.sum([vd[xi] for xi in my_vars])==100)

LP.solve(disp=True)

for xi in my_vars:
    print(xi,vd[xi].value[0])
print ('Cost: ' + str(LP.options.OBJFCNVAL))
```

This was successful.

But suppose I have variables coefficients as LHS and the criteria data as RHS, in data frame format,

for example;

```
Coef = [['x1', 33, 8.8, 0.2, 0.1], ['x2', 24, 4.5, 2, 0.5], ['x3', 82, '', '', '']]
LHS = pd.DataFrame(Coef, columns=['Name', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'])
LHS.set_index('Name')
and
goals = [['p1', 30], ['p2', 5], ['p3', 0.7], ['p4', 0.2]]
RHS = pd.DataFrame(goals, columns=['property', 'goal'])
```

I want to construct constraints dynamically using LHS and RHS data in for loop.
I did as below,

```
for i in range(len(RHS)):
    LP.Equation(LP.sum([LHS.iloc[list(my_vars).index(xi), i]*vd[xi] for xi in my_vars]) >= RHS.iloc[i,1])
```

but there were errors.

> ---
>
> APMonitor, Version 0.9.2
> APMonitor Optimization Suite
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  --------- APM Model Size ------------
> ```
>
> Each time step contains
> Objects      :            6
> Constants    :            0
> Variables    :           28
> Intermediates:            0
> Connections  :           24
> Equations    :           22
> Residuals    :           22
> @error: Model Expression  *** Error in
> syntax of function string: Invalid element: x1
>
> Position: 7                     v9-(((x1)*(v1)))
> ?
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> LP.solve(disp=True)
>
> File
> "/opt/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gekko/gekko.py",
> line 2130, in solve
> raise Exception(apm_error)
>
> Exception: @error: Model Expression  *** Error in syntax of function
> string: Invalid element: x1
>
> Position: 7                     v9-(((x1)*(v1)))
> ?

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple things that you needed to do to prepare your Pandas dataframe correctly. Here is a script that puts everything together and gives a successful solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
my_vars = ['x1','x2','x3']

# stored as dictionaries
Cost = {'x1':100,'x2':125,'x3':80}
Min = {'x1':0,'x2':0,'x3':0}
Max = {'x1':70,'x2':40,'x3':15}

Coef = [['x1', 33, 8.8, 0.2, 0.1],\
        ['x2', 24, 4.5, 2.0, 0.5],\
        ['x3', 82, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
LHS = pd.DataFrame(Coef,\
                   columns=['Name','p1','p2','p3','p4'])
LHS = LHS.set_index('Name')
print(LHS.head())

goals = [['p1', 30], ['p2', 5], ['p3', 0.7], ['p4', 0.2]]
RHS = pd.DataFrame(goals, columns=['property', 'goal'])
RHS = RHS.set_index('property')
print(RHS.head())

LP = GEKKO(remote=False)
va = LP.Array(LP.Var, (len(my_vars)))  # array
vd = {}                                # dictionary
for i,xi in enumerate(my_vars):
    vd[xi] = va[i]
    vd[xi].lower = Min[xi]
    vd[xi].upper = Max[xi]

for yi in LHS.columns.values:
    LP.Equation(LP.sum([LHS[yi][xi]*vd[xi] for xi in my_vars]) \
                >= RHS['goal'][yi])

# Cost function
LP.Minimize(LP.sum([Cost[xi]*vd[xi] for xi in my_vars])) 

LP.solve(disp=False)

print('\n---Solution---')
for xi in my_vars:
    print(xi,vd[xi].value[0])
print ('Total Cost: ' + str(LP.options.OBJFCNVAL))
```

The Pandas dataframes show the constants.

```
      p1   p2   p3   p4
Name                   
x1    33  8.8  0.2  0.1
x2    24  4.5  2.0  0.5
x3    82  0.0  0.0  0.0
          goal
property      
p1        30.0
p2         5.0
p3         0.7
p4         0.2
```

The solution to the problem is below:

```
---Solution---
x1 0.40506330168
x2 0.31898731988
x3 0.10947823632
Total Cost: 89.138004059
```

This is okay for small to moderate sized problems. However, if you have a large-scale Linear Programming (LP) problem then you may want to consider some of the more efficient methods in Gekko for solving LP problems. Instead of building the equations yourself:

```py
for yi in LHS.columns.values:
    LP.Equation(LP.sum([LHS[yi][xi]*vd[xi] for xi in my_vars]) \
                >= RHS['goal'][yi])
```

you can let Gekko do it for you with the `axb` function (see example [linear programming problems](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/LinearProgramming)).

```py
A = np.array(LHS.values).T
b = np.array(RHS.values)
LP.axb(A,b,x=va,etype='>=',sparse=False)
```

Gekko can exploit sparsity in the `A` and `b` constant matrices to deliver an efficient solution for 100,000+ variables. Gekko uses nonlinear programming (NLP) solvers to find a solution to LP problems so that may also limit the speed of solution, especially if you have 1M+ variables.